# Is there required number of rows to run the DLNM package

Tags: r

When I use the example of DLNM package from [Distributed lag linear and non-linear models for time series data](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dlnm/vignettes/dlnmTS.pdf), and only 200 rows of data are retained by parameters.

Here is all R code that I've run:

```
if(require(dlnm)==FALSE){install.packages("dlnm");require(dlnm)} 

chicagoNMMAPS = chicagoNMMAPS[1:200,]

cb1.pm <- crossbasis(chicagoNMMAPS$pm10, lag=15, argvar=list(fun="lin"),arglag=list(fun="poly",degree=4))
summary(cb1.pm)

cb1.o3 <- crossbasis(chicagoNMMAPS$o3, lag=5,argvar=list(fun="thr",thr=40.3), arglag=list(fun="integer"))
summary(cb1.o3)

cb1.temp <- crossbasis(chicagoNMMAPS$temp, lag=3, argvar=list(df=5), arglag=list(fun="strata", breaks=1))
summary(cb1.temp)

if(require(splines)==FALSE){install.packages("splines");require(splines)} 
model1 <- glm(death ~ cb1.pm + cb1.temp + cb1.o3 + ns(time,7*14)+ dow, family=quasipoisson(), chicagoNMMAPS)

pred1.pm <- crosspred(cb1.pm, model1, at=0:20, bylag=0.2, cumul=TRUE)
```

When I ran the `pred1.pm <- crosspred(cb1.pm, model1, at=0:20, bylag=0.2, cumul=TRUE)`, it shows :

```
Error in crosspred(cb1.pm, model1, at = 0:20, bylag = 0.2, cumul = TRUE) : coef/vcov not consistent with basis matrix. See help(crosspred)
```

> I have read https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/482328/error-coef-vcov-not-consistent-with-basis-matrix, but I'm still feel confusing.

Is there required number of rows to run the DLNM package.

Thanks for your help.

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Chinese (Traditional)_Taiwan.950 
[2] LC_CTYPE=Chinese (Traditional)_Taiwan.950   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Chinese (Traditional)_Taiwan.950
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                                
[5] LC_TIME=Chinese (Traditional)_Taiwan.950    

attached base packages:
[1] splines   stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[8] base     

other attached packages:
[1] dlnm_2.4.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.0  Matrix_1.2-17   tools_3.6.0     mgcv_1.8-28    
[5] nlme_3.1-139    grid_3.6.0      tsModel_0.6     lattice_0.20-38
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a required number of rows - I just ran the example code, with `chicagoNMMAPS` as 200 rows, and it all worked fine with no error messages.

I expect the issue is that you have made `cb1.pm` before you selected just the first 200 rows of `chicagoNMAPS`. Move the line `chicagoNMMAPS = chicagoNMMAPS[1:200,]` to the beginning of the script, and try it again.

Comment: Thanks  for your quick response. I've updated my question to explaim issue clearly. when I got error message , I ran the first 200 rows of `chicagoNMAPS` before `cb1.pm`.

Comment: @HsiangYunChan Well in answer to your question, there is no required number of rows. The error is clearly related to you adding cb1.o3 to the model - if you don't include that (as in the example) then the code will run. So is your question "why does adding cb1.o3 produce an error"? If so, maybe you need to edit it again.